# Writing C++ vector of pairs to a textfile

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stdvector

I have a `vector` of `pair`s named `vec1`. What is the (fastest) way to write that to a text file (in Linux)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>   
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip> 

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<float>>> vec1 { {1,{0.11,0.12,0.13}},
        {2,{0.14,0.15,0.16}}, {3,{0.17,0.18,0.19}} };    
}
```

I was trying something like this:

```
std::ofstream fout("file.txt");
fout << std::setprecision(4);

for(auto const& x : vec1)
    fout << x << '\n';
```

but I get an error:

> error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in insertion operator for `std::pair<T, U>`. You can either make one yourself or print out the fields manually:

```
for (auto const& x : vec1) {
    fout << x.first << ": "; 
    for (float f : x.second) fout << f << " ";
    fout << '\n';
}
```